# Search Firebase Realtime Database using a string starting with a symbol ("+")

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to store information about users. In the user profile data, I have a field called "phone" (which is index on via the firebase rules).

When I search using `.equalTo("12345678")` it returns the data just fine.

But when I search using `.equalTo("+1234567890")` it does not work and returns nothing (there is a user profile with phone "+1234567890".

It seems that if the string starts with "+" (or maybe other symbols too), the search does not work, unless I should be doing something additional.

I have tried prefixing the search string with "\" just in case the symbol has to be "escaped", but firebase throws an error about invalid json format.

EDIT:
Sample Data:

```
{
    "userProfile": {
        "02c9x5dwuAMIiOc6venexgBLV2I2": {
            "email": "email@domain.com",
            "firstName": "firstname",
            "lastName": "surname",
            "phone": "+3571234567890",
            "phoneVerified": true,
            "userDevices": [
                {
                    "appVersion": "3.01.07",
                    "platform": "android",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

sample firebase function to query by phone:

```
const phone = "+3571234567890";
await admin.database(fbData).ref('/userProfile')
    .orderByChild('phone')
    .equalTo(phone)
    .once('value')
    .then(userSnap => {
 
    })
```

Comment: How do you write the value, can you show the code? Also can you show a screenshot of your Realtime Database console?

Comment: I call the firebase.database().ref(`/userProfile/` + userId).update({phone: newPhone}) method. newPhone is a string variable containing the phone number (which could start with +<countrycode>)
The phone is stored properly in firebase, i.e. "+3571234567890", I verify this both by looking at the object in firebase, and also when I retrieve the user using the user KEY. But when I search by phone, if the phone starts with "+", the entry is not found, whereas if the phone does not start with "+", the entry is properly returned. I can't show a screenshot as it contains real user data (production)

Comment: I tested it and it does work for me with a String. You may double check that it is really saved as a string...

Comment: It shows "Abc" next to it in firebase console, and it is enclosed in ( " ) when I try to edit it, so I guess it is a string. In any case in what other format could a "+" be stored other than a string?

I also developed a C# program that works against the firebase database and I can confirm that the value is retrieved as a string in there too. But searching by phone (again in C#) doesn't work either....

Comment: If you edit the field in the console you can see the type of the field via a kind of icon on the right of the field. Do you see the "ABC" icon?

Comment: Yes, it shows "Abc" as I have written above

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t see how I could help you anymore… As I said, tested it and it does work for me with a String

Comment: This works for me as well. My guess is the data you're sending to firebase isn't what you think it is. Can you please include the EXACT code you're using to do the query with and then also include a screenshot of your Firestore showing the document that contains the data you're querying for?

Comment: @Jay I'm not using the Firestore, I'm using Firebase Realtime Database. The c# version of the query is:

           var userRef = await fb.Child("userProfile")
                .OrderBy("phone")
                .EqualTo(phone)
                .OnceAsync<UserProfile>()
                ;

where phone is a string variable containing the phone number I'm searching for. I can't include a screenshot of actual data as they are real user values (the system is in production), and if I edit them it defeats the purpose, but I can confirm it's a string (quoted with " and ABC icon if I try to edit)

Comment: If I search for a phone without the prefix "+<countrycode>", the same query code using the same firebase realtime database, finds the record just fine. Only when searching for an existing phone that has the "+" prefix it does not

Comment: The typescript version of the query (in firebase functions) is:
await admin.database(fbData).ref('/userProfile').orderByChild('phone').equalTo(phone).once('value').then(userSnap => { ..... }

Comment: Yeah, I saw you're using RTDB but typed Firestore instead. lol. No matter though ; an "+" (or really any ascii char) will not affect how the query works. We really need to see a set of sample data and your actual code in the **question** (code and structures are hard to read in comments). Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and to get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure, and just change any sensitive data.

Comment: Json structure of sample userProfile:

```
{
 "userProfile": {
  "02c9x5dwuAMIiOc6venexgBLV2I2": {
   "email": "email@domain.com",
   "firstName": "firstname",
   "lastName": "surname",
   "phone": "+3571234567890",
   "phoneVerified": true,
   "userDevices": [
    {
     "appVersion": "3.01.07",
     "platform": "android",
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```
firebase function to query:
```
const phone = "+3571234567890";
await admin.database(fbData).ref('/userProfile)
 .orderByChild('phone')
 .equalTo(phone)
 .once('value)
 .then(userSnap => {
  
 })
```

Comment: I tried using triple-backticks to format my comment as code, but it still scrambles everything.... not sure what I've done wrong....

Comment: https://pastebin.com/68fmKX74

Comment: also added sample data & code in the question as you suggested (just saw that :) )
thanks!

Comment: I used your exact code and sample data and it works correctly for me. How are you determining that  "nothing is returned"? Do you have any rules in place? Perhaps something is trying to validate phone number is in a certain format?

Comment: I check that
if (userSnap !== null && userSnap.hasChildren()) {
} else {
}

and it always goes in the Else (when the phone I'm searching starts with "+"), so either userSnap is null or it does not have any children...  When I search with a string of just numbers (e.g. "12345678") and there is a record with this phone, it finds it

Comment: I am thinking that field in Firestore is actually an Int. As per above, can you please double check what's actually stored in Firestore? Open the Firestore console and navigate to the document in question and select it. The documents contents will be displayed on the right. Click the field to select it. It will then tell you the TYPE of field: String, Number, Array etc. Report back your findings.

Comment: @jay, thanks for the suggestion, but as I said before, this is a firebase realtime database, not firestore, the field is a string, indicated by the fact that when I click on it to edit it, the "Abc" icon appears next to it, which means it's a string. Also the value is enclosed in quotation marks ( " ) as can also be seen in the Json export I added in my post.

Comment: Just thought of something and did some tests. 
I have a user with "1234567890" in the phone field. Entry is found as expected.
I added a "+357" at the beginning. Entry is NOT found (not correct).
I added a character "a" before the "+". Entry is NOT found (not correct)
I removed the "+" and left the phone as "a3571234567890". Entry IS found (correct).

I tried a crazy idea, and added a minus "-" instead of "+", i.e. phone: "-3571234567890". Entry IS found !!! (correct).

It seems it doesnt like the "+" symbol in the string being searched (or supplied to the .equalTo() method.....

Comment: Entering data via the console can be tricky; entering +123456789 will convert to a number automatically and the + is removed. So I am still concerned about the data format. I just built an app and have data in firebase; `uid_0` with a child node `phone` and a value of `+123456789` (shows ABC so it's a string) and a second child node `uid_1` with a child node of `phone` and a value of `123456789` (also ABC so it's a string). When I run a query equal to `+123456789`, uid_0 is returned. When the query is `123456789`, uid_1 is returned. So it's working for me.

Comment: The "+" is not removed, I can see it in the console. If it was removed, then the "-" would also be removed, but searching with the "-" returns the entry correctly, searching with the "+" even if it's NOT at the start but at the 2nd position and the string starts with "a", i.e. "a+12345", the entry is NOT found.... I dont know why it works on your end, it doesnt on mine, neither from a c# program nor from nodeJS firebase function....

Comment: I think you mis-read what I wrote. When actually *using the console to enter data*, if you type +123456, the console will remove the + and store the 123456 as a number. That's *only* when actually entering that in the console. Writing a string of data from an app is a different story. A string of "a+12345" will always be found with a query for "a+12345"; i've never seen it fail. As a test, I suggest creating a new collection 'Test' and add a couple of documents to it that have a phone property and a string of "a+12345" and query that.

Comment: @Jay sorry I was away and didnt see your message sooner. You refer to "collection" and "documents"... this terminology is used in the FireStore database. Maybe your comment of a query never failing for "a+12345" is also for firestore... I am using Realtime DB, and I test it thoroughly as per my comment on Mar 21 at 5:58. I am an experienced developer with 32+ years on the field, unless my eyes are failing me, these were my findings. Did you try it with a realtime db and not firestore?

Comment: Also please note that I have an ".indexon: [phone]" in my rules, maybe having an index on the field being searched creates the problem.... could you try that in a realtime db having an index on the field being searched and tell me what you find?

Comment: My apologies - my brain was in Firestore land so my reference to collections and documents was actually referencing nodes and child nodes. All of the testing I did was in RTDB. As I mentioned in my comment above I was entering data in the console and it was tagging strings as ABC, which only happens in the RTDB. I am still working on duplicating the issue; I cannot make querying "a+12345" fail no matter what I do. I would think that if a query like that were to fail, it would be a huge bug and been revealed years ago. Wish I could duplicate it!